# Filled csv file leads to CORS error wherease it doesn't when file only has columns

Tags: reactjs, laravel, csv, axios, react-query

I have a Laravel API, returning a CSV file.

When the csv file is only populated with columns headers and small content, I can download it from my client application (react).

Whenever the csv file has more than 50 rows and starts to grow, it returns CORS error on client side, but not on Insomnia, where I have all my csv content.

I believe it is a problem of size, but I can't find out where to edit it, if it is backend limitation (which I believe it's not since I can retrieve data from Insomnia), or front end.

I'm using react query with axios in a reactjs project.

I edited my cors.php to this :

```
// 'paths' => ['api/*', 'broadcasting/auth'],
    'paths' => ['*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,
```

**EDIT** :

It start issuing when I got more than 50 rows. The file size is small (>10Ko) and the query time is under 4 seconds.

It might be good to know that all other requests are working fine and I'm not issuing with cors error.